# Build Linq Expression to return all questions that have keywords assigned to it that match a list of keyword ids?

Tags: c#, linq, expression

I am having an issue with creating a proper Expression using Linq, and I hope that you can help me...

I have the following relationships:

```
Question (1) --- (n) QuestionsKeywords (n) --- (1) Keyword 
PK Id                PK Id                         PK Id
string DisplayAs     int QuestionId                string DisplayAs
                     int KeywordId
```

So, a Question can have many Keywords assigned to it, and a Keyword can be assign to many Questions.

The data model has a Question with a QuestionsKeywords collection.

The user selects keywords in a CheckedListBox control that he/she wants to use to filter the list of Questions in a data grid.  I create a List keywordIds that contains the record id for each of selected keywords.  This list will be used to filter the list of questions later...

Finally... The question...

How can I implement an Expression that will return all Questions that have any QuestionKeyword entities that have a KeywordId in keywordIds?

I've tried the following, but get an runtime exception, which follows.

```
Expression<Func<QuestionEntity, bool>> expression = 
q => q.QuestionsKeywords.Any(qk => keywordIds.Any(k => k.Id == qk.Keyword.Id));
```

Thank you for your time and suggestions!

Mike

System.InvalidCastException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467262
  Message=Unable to cast object of type 'System.Linq.Expressions.ConstantExpression' to type 'SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionClasses.SetExpression'.
  Source=SD.LLBLGen.Pro.ORMSupportClasses
  StackTrace:
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.MemberAccessEvaluator.HandleLinqExpressionAsSetExpression(LinqExpressionAsSetExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\MemberAccessEvaluator.cs:line 183
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 192
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleAllAnyExpression(AllAnyExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 564
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 140
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleLambdaExpression(LambdaExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 1377
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 296
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleAllAnyExpression(AllAnyExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 565
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 140
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleLambdaExpression(LambdaExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 1377
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 296
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleWhereExpression(WhereExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 974
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 216
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleSelectExpression(SelectExpression expressionToHandle, SelectExpression newInstance) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 817
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleSelectExpression(SelectExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 796
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 207
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleSelectExpression(SelectExpression expressionToHandle, SelectExpression newInstance) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 817
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleSelectExpression(SelectExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 796
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 207
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleSortClauseExpression(SortClauseExpression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 640
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ExpressionHandlers.GenericExpressionHandler.HandleExpression(Expression expressionToHandle) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExpressionHandlers\GenericExpressionHandler.cs:line 213
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.LLBLGenProProviderBase.HandleExpressionTree(Expression expression) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\LLBLGenProProviderBase.cs:line 189
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.LLBLGenProProviderBase.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\LLBLGenProProviderBase.cs:line 129
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.LLBLGenProProviderBase.System.Linq.IQueryProvider.Execute(Expression expression) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\LLBLGenProProviderBase.cs:line 679
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.LLBLGenProQuery`1.Execute() in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\LLBLGenProQuery.cs:line 86
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.LLBLGenProQuery`1.SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.ILLBLGenProQuery.ExecuteTResult in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\LLBLGenProQuery.cs:line 130
       at SD.LLBLGen.Pro.LinqSupportClasses.QueryableExtensionMethods.Execute[TResult](IQueryable source) in c:\Myprojects\VS.NET Projects\LLBLGen Pro v4.1\Frameworks\LLBLGen Pro\RuntimeLibraries\ORMSupportClasses\Linq\ExtensionMethods.cs:line 146
       at ContentLibrary.MainForm.FilterButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\PROJECTS\ContentLibrary\ContentLibrary\MainForm.cs:line 1282
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mevent)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ButtonBase.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Button.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at ContentLibrary.Program.Main() in c:\PROJECTS\ContentLibrary\ContentLibrary\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is because keywordIds is a collection that exists in memory, while the other collections exist in your DB. Try passing the collection of ids to the closure as an array of integers instead.

```
var keywordIdsArray = keywordIds.Select(x => x.Id).ToArray();

Expression<Func<QuestionEntity, bool>> expression = 
    q => q.QuestionsKeywords.Any(qk => keywordIdsArray.Contains(qk.Keyword.Id));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, Carlos!  I made the changes and everything is working perfectly! :)

Mike